# Get all set enum names from enum flags

Tags: c#, enums, flags

How can I cast the return enum value to its integer value?

I want to get all flags which are set in the `_allVisibleDays` enum as integer values just like:

`Tuesday` and `Wednesday` are set then I want to cast these names into a `DayOfWeek` enum to get the integer values:

So `Tuesday` returns me `2` and `Wednesday` `3` instead of `2` and `4` of the below enum.

I have found this method on SO:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetFlags()
{
   foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(VisibleDayOfWeek)))
     if (_allVisibleDays.HasFlag(value))
       yield return (int) value;
}
```

but I can ot make it work just for the simple example of casting an enum (value above) to the integer...

```
private VisibleDayOfWeek _allVisibleDays;


        [Flags]
        enum VisibleDayOfWeek : int
        {
            None = 0,
            Monday = 1, 
            Tuesday = 2,
            Wednesday = 4,
            Thursday = 8,
            Friday = 16,
            Saturday = 32,
            Sunday = 64
        }
```

Comment: Your stated aims appear contradictory. Cna you provide a sample input with its corresponding output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `VisibleDayOfWeek` is a `Flags` enumeration, and [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not, there is no direct corresponding translation between the two (for example, `VisibleDayOfWeek.Friday` is 16, while `DayOfWeek.Friday` is 5). Especially as these are just days of the week and probably won't change in the future (I hope!) I think the best bet here is just write a simple utility method with checks:

```
public IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> ConvertFromVisible(VisibleDayOfWeek visibleDay)
{
    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Monday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Monday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Monday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Tuesday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Tuesday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Wednesday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Wednesday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Thursday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Thursday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Thursday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Friday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Friday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Friday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Saturday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Saturday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Saturday;

    if ((visibleDay & VisibleDayOfWeek.Sunday) == VisibleDayOfWeek.Sunday)
        yield return DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
```

This has the benefit of automatically returning the `DayOfWeek` enumeration rather than the integers to cast later as well.

In addition, since this skips reflection, it should be more performant as well as more resistant to value changes (though I doubt this will happen anyway).

EDIT: If you want to tweak the order they're returned (say you want to start from Sunday and go to Saturday) you can just alter the order of the lines above easily.

Comment: You have clearly recognized the problem. I know of the & operator and checking the value but hoped there would be a clever algorythm to return all set values with a one-liner ;-) Of course your solution works and yes later if needed I can cast the dayofweek value to its integer. My final task in the UI is to fill a CheckBoxList with those DayOfWeek values where the first element with index 0 is Sunday of course :) thanks!

Comment: Well if you want a "one-liner", you can use this method (or extension method), you can even create a static lookup table `Dictionary<VisibleDayOfWeek, DayOfWeek>`. Hope it all works out!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `Enum` array and check the index.

```
public int GetEnumIndex(VisibleDayOfWeek day, bool ToBeConvertedToDoW)
{
     var allValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VisibleDayOfWeek));
     for (int i = 0; i <  allValues.Length ; i++)
     {
         if ((VisibleDayOfWeek)allValues.GetValue(i) == day)
         {
             //if you plan to convert to a DayOfWeek, this will return the
             //index for the DoW enum
             if(ToBeConvertedToDoW)
                return (i % 7);
             else //else return the actual index from VisibleDayOfWeek enum
                return i;
         }
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

Comment: If the intent is to convert to [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this might cause issues as it runs from Sunday to Saturday whereas `VisibleDayOfWeek` goes from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Sorry, I missed that. I think modding 7 should solve the issue if I understand correctly. `0` can be handled depending on what OP wants to convert `None` to as a `DayOfWeek`.